# Converting Entity to GeoJSON with Cesium

Tags: geojson, cesium, turf

I know there is a way to load entities from a GeoJSON using `GeoJsonDataSource` but is there any way to do the opposite: get any entity as a GeoJSON representation?

My goal is to use Turf.JS with Cesium.JS geometries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have a solution to export to [json](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html#c=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) and for export it to [kml](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Export%20KML.html).

Everything is obtained from this official [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/KT2brToFGR8) of Cesium.

They are links that talk about the question and there isn't method to do that native in Cesium, such as [exportKml](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/cd1691770e6198f3e7e3e997b3a1c23bed7b30a8/Source/DataSources/exportKml.js#L297).

To implement exportJson (for example), it should be done using pure js or Turf as you did.

You can use the exportKml code to help create the result you are looking for.

Another way you can try is to export to **KML** and convert the result xml to json. For example using [togeojson](https://github.com/tmcw/togeojson#readme)

```
Cesium.exportKml({
     entities: entityCollection
 })
  .then(function(result) {
    // The XML string is in result.kml
    // Convert Kml to GeoJSON (It's just an idea)
       json = toGeoJSON.kml(result)
  });
```